# What is written on these paintings and does it have any meaning?

Tags: translation, meaning, names

Someone I know has a small business in buying/selling things.
She asked if I know what the painting says as I know a limited amount of Japanese. while I couldn't read it even if it was Japanese, I believe it to probably be Chinese. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: art1]

[image: art2]

Comment: p1:  荣贵齐眉
p2：四时美艳

Comment: 牡丹象征着富贵和辉煌, 玫瑰象征着美丽和爱情

Answer (score 1):

The first picture says 荣贵齐眉(TC: 榮貴齊眉) and means "honour and wealth be on the same level as your eyebrows", a metaphor for high level of honour and wealth.

The second picture says 四时美艳(TC: 四時美艷) and means "beautiful in all four seasons".

Comment: 榮貴= honored and wealthy; [齊眉](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E9%BD%8A%E7%9C%89/734409) = harmonious marriage

Comment: It is interesting to compare the differences, if any, between 荣贵齐眉 and 白发齐眉?

Comment: tang ho is correct, I recommend an edit be made to translate 榮貴齊眉 as something like "flourish in a harmonious  marriage" or similar (◐‿◑)

Comment: @WayneCheah to me the first emphasizes being successful and living comfortably materially.  the latter emphasizes living together your whole life and living comfortably emotionally.  Although in real life they are probably just interchangable generic blessings haha （＾ν＾）